# Solution for calling a function doing lots of stuff in it by Cron?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

```
function cronProcess() {
    # > 100,000 users 
    $users = $this->UserModel->getUsers();

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        # Do lots of database Insert/Update/Delete, HTTP request stuff
    }
}
```

The problem happens when the number of users reaches ~ 100,000.

I called the function by CURL via CronTab.

So what is the best solution for this?

Comment: Instead of performing all of them in one go, perform a small amount, a number of times on a regular time lapse. This will require that you store where you got up to etc.

Comment: @Tim: It seems to be quite hard, because the after statements have to use the return data of the before statements.

Comment: Use pagination -> get only a specific limit of results, process the results, then get the next bunch of results.

Comment: @CodyKL Yes, there seems no way else to go :D

Comment: does it need to be a cron job ? eg some promise of service to your users ? and, what is `the problem` ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg: yes, it must be cron. The problem is, it got timed out when time code had executed too long. Changing executing time or php/server config is not allowed here

Answer (score 1):

I do a lot of bulk tasks in CakePHP, some processing millions of records. It's certainly possible to do, the key as others suggested is small batches in a loop.

If this is something you're calling from Cron, it's probably easier to use a Shell (< v3.5) or the newer `Command` class (v3.6+) than cURL.

Here's generally how I paginate large batches, including some helpful optional things like a progress bar, turning off hydration to speed things up slightly, and showing how many users/second the script was able to process:

```
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use Cake\Console\Arguments;
use Cake\Console\Command;
use Cake\Console\ConsoleIo;

class UsersCommand extends Command
{
    public function execute(Arguments $args, ConsoleIo $io)
    {
        // I'd guess a Finder would be a more Cake-y way of getting users than a custom "getUsers" function:
        // See https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods
        $usersQuery = $this->UserModel->find('users');

        // Get a total so we know how many we're gonna have to process (optional)
        $total = $usersQuery->count();
        if ($total === 0) {
            $this->abort("No users found, stopping..");
        }

        // Hydration takes extra processing time & memory, which can add up in bulk. Optionally if able, skip it & work with $user as an array not an object:
        $usersQuery->enableHydration(false);

        $this->info("Grabbing $total users for processing");

        // Optionally show the progress so we can visually see how far we are in the process
        $progress = $io->helper('Progress')->init([
            'total' => 10
        ]);

        // Tune this page value to a size that solves your problem:
        $limit = 1000;
        $offset = 0;

        // Simply drawing the progress bar every loop can slow things down, optionally draw it only every n-loops,
        // this sets it to 1/5th the page size:
        $progressInterval = $limit / 5;

        // Optionally track the rate so we can evaluate the speed of the process, helpful tuning limit and evaluating enableHydration effects
        $startTime = microtime(true);
        do {
            $users = $usersQuery->offset($offset)->toArray();
            $count = count($users);
            $index = 0;

            foreach ($users as $user) {
                $progress->increment(1);

                // Only draw occasionally, for speed
                if ($index % $progressInterval === 0) {
                    $progress->draw();
                }

                ### WORK TIME
                # Do your lots of database Insert/Update/Delete, HTTP request stuff etc. here
                ###
            }

            $progress->draw();

            $offset += $limit; // Increment your offset to the next page
        } while ($count > 0);

        $totalTime = microtime(true) - $startTime;
        $this->out("\nProcessed an average " . ($total / $totalTime) . " Users/sec\n");
    }
}
```

> **Checkout these sections in the CakePHP Docs:**
>
> - [Console Commands](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/commands.html)
> - [Command Helpers](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/input-output.html#command-helpers)
> - [Using Finders & Disabling Hydration](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I has been implementing it this way. But the shell got timed out when time code had executed too long. Changing executing time or php/server config is not allowed here.


Maybe Queue is the best way to go
https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-queue